# How to troubleshoot extremely high load averge (over 550)?

Tags: 18.04, mysql, php, cpu-load

I am Ubuntu 18.04 user, running in OVHCloud Datacenter for 3 years with PHP Application and Mysql server on it. For 2.5 years, everything was ok, but in last 6 months i have strange issuee:

- Every 4th Sunday, exactly at 10.30 pm, my Load Average goes extremely high, over 550, and my server crashes.

When this happens I am able to login over ssh, i am able to stop all services, but nothing fixes load average. As soon as I reboot it, it works again for 4 weeks, then the issue re-appears.

Can someone help me how can i troubleshoot what is causing extremely high CPU load average, and why exactly always at the same time?

Please take a look at this picture from htop:

[Htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VaQo.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: what's running on the server?  What is web facing?  High CPU load suggests that *something* is trying to run insanely high intensity processes or queries and since you're showing us `htop` after you've shut services we can't reliably ID what is or isn't doing the overuse of resources.  I notice MySQL there, any chance you're running a website that isn't updated/patched properly and as such there's some type of SQL injection based attack mechanism being used?

Comment: how can i check is it mysql injection?

Comment: See if there is a cronjob sitting in the `/etc/cron.monthly/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not the host at OVH doing something crazy, but something within your machine, then it's likely a `cron` job.

I'd be inclined to look in `/etc/cron.d` for any files which have jobs which are configured to start on that day at that time.

You can probably `grep "^30 22" /etc/cron.d/*` to look for any lines starting with (^) 30 (minutes) past 22 (hours). Or you could just go through each one. I suspect it's some badly configured job in there.

Alternatively it could be something in your crontab `crontab -l` or root's crontab `sudo crontab -l`.

Comment: I already checked cron's, they are empty. Since time interval is always same, Sunday at  22:30, is it possible that Datacentar byitself is doing some thing like backup which screws my hdd and creates high load?

Comment: Is it shared hosting? Could be the provider or maybe even someone else on the same host.

Comment: well it is dedicated server, but not sure how there infrastructure is deployed, maybe storage is shared between servers

Answer (score 0):

One option to diagnose this would be to `dstat` left running in a terminal rather than htop. It's good at spotting the top processes over a period of time.

ssh to the server, and in `screen`, `tmux` or `byobu`, launch dstat with all these options: `dstat --time --cpu --net --disk --sys --load --proc --top-cpu --top-mem --top-io` and leave it running.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: screenshot of dstat]

When the issue starts occurring you can scroll back to the time when it started and look for anomalous processes. Especially in the "most expensive" last three columns for cpu, memory and io. It also lets you see whether the load average (middle columns) is freaking out immediately, or ramping up over time. May give some clues.